# YouTube API: Multiple Embeds on the Same Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

How can I embed different YouTube videos at different places on the page using YouTube API?  (This means they can **not** share the same `<div>` "player".)  They also start at different times based on different `onclick` events.  My code works fine when only one video is on the page, but for the life of me I cannot figure out the code to let this all work with 2 or more!

At first I was trying to simply add multiple instances of the code where I wanted each one to be, but that wasn't working.  I read that all the players need to be added to one `<script>`, so I tried this:

*(Also, does it matter WHERE on the page the `<script>` is and where the `<div>`s are?  Can the `<script>` write to a `<div>` no matter where they are on the page?)*

Anyway, here's the code I'm using:

```
// inside other containers with with relative and absolute positioning
// that fadeIn and fadeOut using jQuery
<div id="video1"></div>

// inside other containers with with relative and absolute positioning
// that fadeIn and fadeOut using jQuery
<div id="video2"></div>


<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player1;
var player2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player1 = new YT.Player('video1',{
                width: '320',
                height: '216',
                videoId: 'VIDEO_ID_1',
                playerVars: {rel: 0, controls: 0, autohide: 1, disablekb: 1, enablejsapi: 1, modestbranding: 1, showinfo: 0 },
                events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange1 } });;
    player2 = new YT.Player('video2',{
                width: '320',
                height: '216',
                videoId: 'VIDEO_ID_2',
                playerVars: {rel: 0, controls: 0, autohide: 1, disablekb: 1, enablejsapi: 1, modestbranding: 1, showinfo: 0 },
                events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange2 } });; }

function startVideo1() {
            player1.playVideo();
            $('#video_box_B1').delay(1000).fadeIn();
            $("#video_box_B1").delay(20000).hide();
        };
function onPlayerStateChange1(event) {        
            if(event.data === 2) {
                $("#video_box_B1").hide();
            }
        }
function startVideo2() {
            player2.playVideo();
            $('#video_box_E5').delay(1000).fadeIn();
            $("#video_box_E5").delay(20000).hide();
        };
function onPlayerStateChange2(event) {        
            if(event.data === 2) {
                $("#video_box_E5").hide();
            }
        }
</script>

// onclick triggers at various places on the page
<img src="image_1.jpg" onclick="startVideo1()" />
<img src="image_2.jpg" onclick="startVideo2()" />
```

Is there anyone who can tell what I'm doing wrong?  BTW, those containers fading in and out works perfectly if I'm using a still image, text-only, or with only one video on the page, so it's not those fading containers causing this.  It's got to be the YouTube script.  Can anyone help?

Comment: How and when are the functions startVideo1() and startVideo2() called ?

Comment: I added them under the current code for your reference.  I use `<img src="image_1.jpg" onclick="startVideo1()" />` and `<img src="image_2.jpg" onclick="startVideo2()" />` at different places on the page.  This works perfectly when there's only one YouTube API embed, so I know this trigger method isn't the problem.  The problem is the way I'm trying to put more than one video on the page.

Comment: Reading your other comment, it seems to work already the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working in this jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/catuhimo/3/edit

What browser are you trying it out in? If you're using Safari bleeding edge Version 8.0 (10538.39.41) on Yosemite, jsfiddle and jsBin had some trouble rendering things. I tried out your code on  Chrome latest and replaced the placeholders with actual video IDs and it worked.

Does that help? Am I missing the point of the your question? Based on what you asked, it seems to work ok for me.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Mavericks.  I have NO idea what I was doing before apparently, because YES this works in jsbin.  Perhaps I had some small typo in my code that I happened to fix here.  I will have to double check my code in my page, or maybe just write it from scratch.  I can't believe I had my own question answered this whole time!  :-(  Thank you for showing me what I apparently already knew!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up about it! Glad it works now :) Also, there's ways to refactor your code so you don't have to manually construct each and every instance of a video player; would that be helpful in your app/page? I can post some code later if it's relevant to what you're working on

Comment: I have a "system" for editing the code, although I have to replicate each time I create a page with more than one YouTube embed.  I'm not sure how much I'd need it, but maybe your code would be helpful if others find this page in a Google search for a problem they're trying to solve.  :-)